# WPF DataGrid Добавляются пустые строки

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Пытаюсь заполнить DataGrid примитивными данными. Но при каждом добавлении данных все ячейки пусты. Гуглить уже нет сил. Помогите, это что баг фреймворка?

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="false" MinWidth="400" x:Name="EnemyInfoGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Дата последнего обнаружения" Binding="{Binding Path=LastDetectedDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss\}}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

public class SystemInfoDataGridModel
{
    public DateTime LastDetectedDate;
    public EnemyInfo EnemyInfo;
}

EnemyInfoGrid.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<SystemInfoDataGridModel>()
{
    new SystemInfoDataGridModel() { LastDetectedDate = DateTime.Now }
};
```

Почему интересно добавляет пустые ячейки? Может проект побился?

Comment: Можно скрин грида?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привязка в WPF работает только со *свойствами*, но не с полями!

Попробуйте так:

```
public class SystemInfoDataGridModel
{
    public DateTime LastDetectedDate { get; set; }
    public EnemyInfo EnemyInfo { get; set; }
}
```